# Use PowerShell to open a file

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, automation

Is there a command to open a project item (such as a class file) from Package Manager Console (a.k.a. PowerShell) within Visual Studio? That is the same thing that would happen when I double-click the file in Solution Explorer.

I tried using `Invoke-Item` but that happens to open a new instance of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$DTE.ExecuteCommand(“File.OpenFile”, "a path to your file")
```

You can refer to a local project file this way:

```
$path = [System.IO.Path]
$file = $path::Combine($path::GetDirectoryName($project.FileName), “your local path”)
$DTE.ExecuteCommand(“File.OpenFile”, $file)
```

Comment: How can I pipe it? I appended it to the end of my command, but it says "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline."

Comment: Found it myself. You just need to prepend your command with an ampersand (`&`) sign and it will work.

Comment: Any idea on how to silently ignore errors files that do not exist or are not part of the visual studio solution?