# Open file in visual studio via nuget manager console

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015

## context information

I Use the scaffolder nuget package to make database upgrade classes. by calling `scaffold dbupgrade` in the package manager console.

De upgrade powershell file ends with: `Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate ....`

### What i want

It all works great and generates a class for me and adds it to the project file but: I would like to open the generated file in my solution.

Is this possible? and how would i go from here?

I use visual studio 2015 Community edition.

#### What I tried

I tried commands such as `Open-File`, `Open-Document` but these do not exist.

Comment: To comment on this. i did not found a solution yet, although i did not spend a lot of time on this, trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution on another stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28426592/1275832

the solution would be:

```
$DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile", "App.config")
```

For a nuget package `Install.ps1` you could do:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

//Get specific file
$file = $project.ProjectItems.Item("`$rootnamespace`$.nuspec")

//Get its location
$location = $proj.ProjectItems.Item("App.config").Properties['LocalPath'].Value

//Open the file in the IDE
$project.DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile", $location)
```